# How to change application registration for existing (i.e. deployed) Microsoft Bot Framework bot?

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, registration, azure-resource-group

I want to be able to change my application registration for an existing Microsoft Bot Framework (v4.4+) bot. Microsoft doesn't provide documentation on how to do so. Does anyone know how this could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft App ID cannot be changed. You can only generate a new passoword by clicking on the Manage link. Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-settings?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) for details.

[image]

Comment: To confirm, you're saying that you can not change the application registration for an existing LUIS app?

Comment: @EricHansen  If you deployed the bot to azure bot service, yes, we can not change the application id which means we can not change the application registration for an existing bot app. You can find this information in the document I provided.